# Ruby -v gives me one version and Gemfile gives me another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm in a local repository running the command

`bundle install --without production`

and I get an error message saying

`Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.2.2`

I just installed Ruby version 2.2.2 and using the `gem environment` command I'm able to see I have version 2.2.2 however, ruby -v gives me

`ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`

I have tried adding 2.2.2 to my .ruby-version file in the root directory, as well as updating the bundler and typing `bundle exec rails s`

but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Is your Gemfile specifying a ruby version? This already happened to me in this case.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida Yes, my Gemfile is specifying a ruby version

Comment: @tegon no, I'm not using rvm

Comment: You installed Ruby 2.2.2, okay. But have you set it as default or current?

Comment: No sure how. The instructions I was following to do that didn't specify. I guess they were assuming I never had another version.

Comment: What ruby version management are you using? If the answer is NONE, the rethink your Rails development, my friend. http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com.br/2015/10/dont-give-up-rvm.html

Comment: are you using RBENV? or how did you install ruby-2.2? if not using a version manager (Such as rbenv/rvm) then .ruby-version won't do anything.  you will need to make sure the version you want comes first in your path,etc..

Comment: I'm new to Rails, and this is the tutorial I was following https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Comment: If you followed this tutorial then you are using rbenv. I'm not familiar with it, since I always used rvm. But you'll surely find a way to specify a Ruby version as default with rvenv too. Important is to have your current/default set to the same version your app requires.

Comment: http://makandracards.com/makandra/21545-rbenv-how-to-switch-to-another-ruby-version-temporarily-per-project-or-globally